# Filter specific month in datatables using filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have troubles with filtering one specific month in datatables (inputed via input element).

Here is my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-inline container-fluid mb-2">
  <label for="month_selector">month</label>
  <input type="month" id="month_selector" class="form-control form-control-sm mx-sm-3">
</div>
```

JS:

```js
var dataTable = '';

function initDataTable (target, options) {
  let data = {
    stateSave: true,
    destroy: true,
  }
  
  $.extend(data, options)
  dataTable = $(target)
  dataTable.DataTable(data)
}

$(function () {
  //some other code
  initDataTable('.datatable')
})

//DATEPICKER
$('#month_selector').datepicker({
  "onSelect": function (date) {
    console.log(date)
    minDateFilter = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getTime()
    maxDateFilter = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getTime()
    dataTable.draw()
  }
}).keyup(function () {
    minDateFilter = new Date(this.value.getFullYear(), this.value.getMonth(), 1).getTime()
    maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value.getFullYear(), this.value.getMonth() + 1, 0).getTime()
    dataTable.draw()
})

// Date range filter
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
      if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
        aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
      }

      if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }
)
```

Problem is, that in variable "date" is today's date and it says, that "getFullYear()" is not a function. And also I'm not sure if the filter code is right.

Code is based on [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview)

Do you know, where the problem is?

Comment: For starters, `date` is a string, you have to convert it to a date first using `new Date(date)`, that's why `getFullYear()` is not a function in the `String` prototype. Same thing with `this.value`.

Comment: @msg thanks you. That was the problem too. But there is another issue. I have an error, that dataTable.fnDraw or dataTable.draw is not u function. How do I redraw datatable?